# Get VBA to Evaluate Formula In String

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a table that stores a string representing a formula that I would like to have either Access or VBA evaluate. A few example strings look like:

- table.FirstName & ' ' & table.LastName
- table.LastName & ', ' & table.FirstName
- table.LastName & ', ' & table.FirstName & ' ' & LEFT(table.Middle,1)

Basically, I'm trying to change how different names can be viewed based on entity type, missing information, etc.

Is there any way to force either Access (in a query) or VBA (as part of a custom function) to return what the string is telling it as opposed to the literal value? From the examples above, I would expect:

- table.FirstName table.LastName
- table.LastName, table.FirstName
- table.LastName, table.Firstname, t

Replace by itself won't work, as some of the formatting includes LEFT(table.Name,1) or other functions. I'm just hoping there is a simple way to force the string to be evaluated, rather than having to come up with a complex function.

I apologize if I haven't explained this well, I feel like my attempt to merge the database aspect with the string formatting aspect may not come across clearly. If you have questions please reply and I'll do my best to explain it better.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you explain what you actually want to do with the results? It's not hard to create the result strings in your question (`SomeVariable = "table.FirstName" & ", " & "table.LastName"` will create the string `table.LastName, table.FirstName`, but you probably already figured that out by yourself. So I assume that it's more complicated, but I'm afraid I don't understand the big picture yet. Do you want to run a query like `SELECT table.LastName, table.FirstName FROM table` in the end?

Comment: My ultimate goal is a query in which each value in the "Name" column is formatted according to the format assigned that particular entity in the "Entities" table. So one person may be set to display Last, First while a business may be set to display as CompanyName, but they would each appear as such in the same list. Currently the desired format PK is stored in the entity table; the reason for my "format table" (if you will) is so that the end user can see the possible display formats. I'm open to the idea that my setup is flawed, and if so would appreciate suggestions to improve.

Comment: I think I'll just need to place the logic in a VBA function rather than try to store in the table. I feel that in trying to simplify adding new formats at some point in the future that I may have created a monster!

Answer (score 1):

How about the Microsoft Access [Eval() function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa172212(v=office.11).aspx):

```
?Eval("3 + 1")
4
```

Comment: That was my first thought as well, but it doesn't seem to like strings. VBA throws an error when I try to get it to use Eval like so:

?Eval("Smith & ', ' & John")

Which is one example of what could be passed by the variable. Alternatively, I can also pass table.Last & ', ' & table.First, however then the query also reads it as a literal string rather than tables and fields.

Comment: you failed with "   the right test is ?Eval("""Smith "" & "", "" & ""John""")

Answer (score 0):

You could build an SQL string from your table formulas like:

```
SQL = "Select " & tblFormulas.FormulaField.Value & " From " & Split(tblFormulas.FormulaField.Value, ".")(0) & ";"
```

Not bullet-proof but a start ...

Comment: Thank you. As I read your solution I'm thinking that my design is flawed...I'm probably best off writing a function in VBA that just requires each possible field as an input and then containing the logic there, rather than trying to store and transfer it from a table, as each row could theoretically have a different format.

Answer (score 0):

As you have a special table with formulas you can aim at queries and/or VBA.

1. For VBA you can store code for `eval` function to be run in form of several forms with same set of required fields(that is used in formulas):
   in field `VBAformula` of your special table should resides such string   `me![LastName] & ', ' & me!FirstName & ' ' & LEFT(Me![Middle],1)`
   then in some function you could write:

   formula = dlookup("VBAformula","SpecialTable","id=" & me![HowToViewID])

   Me![ViewAs] = eval(formula)
2. For Queries you can store SQL formula to be used in `UPDATE` query, `SQLformula` with such string:
   `[LastName] & ", " & [FirstName] & " " & LEFT([Middle],1)` then you can build and run SQL:

   formula = dlookup("SQLformula","SpecialTable","id=" & me![HowToViewID])

   currentdb.Execute "UPDATE [table with people] SET [ViewAs] = " & formula & " WHERE peopleID=" & Me![peopleID] & ";" , dbFailOnError

These are examples to show some variants, so there is no error handling or security.